# Node.js mysql connection only works while executed with command prompt

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-modules

I am still new to node.js so I apologize in advance if this question is silly.

First I have tried to execute the test.js with command prompt

conn.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
password: '',
database: 'tgs'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
});

module.exports = connection;
```

test.js

```
function testconnect()
{
  var conn = require('./conn');
  var sql = "INSERT INTO chat_line (line_text) VALUES ('test')";
  conn.query(sql, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  });
}
testconnect();
```

in the command prompt

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\TGS\>node test.js
```

and it works, I did get the input in my database. After that I wanted to try to implement this in my system so I have tried to execute this in php

testing.php

```
<script>
function testalert()
{
  alert("alert1");
  var conn = require('./conn');
  var sql = "INSERT INTO chat_line (line_text) VALUES ('test')";
  conn.query(sql, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  });
  alert("alert2");
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="testalert();">
```

and it doesn't work. The first alert did pop up after clicking the button but the second alert did not, also there is no input in my database.

Comment: You can use html in node it self. In node it is called .ejs if you create project with ejs engine. Then after you have to bind html data to js file.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js and PHP are different technologies, you cannot directly use one in another if you want to interact with one another you will need some mediator like (API, queue, database etc).

try to understand how nodeJs works, there is a dependency of mysql library at line one, which is a middleware helping with dealing with database

var mysql = require('mysql');

above line can only work in nodeJs environment, if you want to use it in PHP then there will be some other library in PHP to do same (I am not PHP guy so cannot help with ideal one here) and you will not need nodeJS at all with your example.

do let me know if I made it clear.